# Golang XML parse

Tags: xml, go

My XML data:

```
<dictionary version="0.8" revision="403605">
    <grammemes>
        <grammeme parent="">POST</grammeme>
        <grammeme parent="POST">NOUN</grammeme>
    </grammemes>
</dictionary>
```

My code:

```
type Dictionary struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"dictionary"`
    Grammemes *Grammemes `xml:"grammemes"`
}

type Grammemes struct {
    Grammemes []*Grammeme `xml:"grammeme"`
}

type Grammeme struct {
    Name string `xml:"grammeme"`
    Parent string `xml:"parent,attr"`
}
```

I get Grammeme.Parent attribute, but i don't get Grammeme.Name. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a field to hold the contents of the current element, you can use the tag `xml:",chardata"`.  The way you've tagged your structure, it is instead looking for a `<grammeme>` sub-element.

So one set of structures you could decode into is:

```
type Dictionary struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name   `xml:"dictionary"`
    Grammemes []Grammeme `xml:"grammemes>grammeme"`
}

type Grammeme struct {
    Name   string `xml:",chardata"`
    Parent string `xml:"parent,attr"`
}
```

You can test out this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/7lQnQOCh0I